# How to emit every n-th value?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

I'm using mousemove event to create an observable.

```
Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove')
```

I need to emit every 10-th event. What do I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can think of four different ways to do it:

**bufferCount()**

```
Observable.range(1, 55)
  .bufferCount(10)
  .map(arr => arr[arr.length - 1])
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

**windowCount()**

```
Observable.range(1, 55)
  .windowCount(10)
  .switchMap(window => window.takeLast(1))
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

**debounce()**

```
let source = Observable.range(1, 55).publish();

source
  .debounce(val => debounceNotifier)
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));

let debounceNotifier = source
  .bufferCount(10)
  .publish();
debounceNotifier.connect();

source.connect();
```

**scan()**

```
Observable.range(1, 55)
  .scan((acc, val) => {
    if (acc.length === 10) {
      acc = [];
    }
    acc.push(val);
    return acc;
  }, [])
  .filter(acc => acc.length === 10)
  .map(acc => acc[acc.length - 1])
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

However, when using `scan()` it'll will discard the last value `55`.

See demo for all of them: https://jsbin.com/yagayot/14/edit?js,console

Comment: I was preparing a Plunkr but this answer says it all ! :)

Comment: @martin, sir, you're amazing! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8):

Here's an even simpler and considerably faster approach, which I tested with RxJS 6:

```
range(1, 10000000)
  .pipe(
    filter(function(value, index) { 
      return index % 10 === 0; 
    }),
  );
```

This code is twice as fast as the `bufferCount` and `windowCount` approaches in the other answer: https://jsperf.com/observable-nth/1

This is likely because the `filter` operator uses a simple counter, instead of having to keep a buffer of the last `n` elements. I assume this is even faster when `n` is larger or the elements themselves are bigger. With RxJS 6, you can also easily make this into your own custom operator:

```
const takeEveryNth = (n: number) => filter((value, index) => index % n === 0);
// usage: rxjs.range(1, 10000000).pipe(takeEveryNth(10));
```

It is also the code used in the official docs explaining how to create custom operators: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.2.2/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Comment: Simple, efficient, and unsurprising. Underrated answer!